# Inputing numbers into a register in avr

Tags: c, assembly, input, variable-assignment, avr

I have an assignment where I must input 3 different numbers into register r16, r17 and r18 and add them up. I've tried looking up how to input numbers into a register but could not figure out how to do it.

http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_IN.html

Would I use this command?

For example

In r16, a

Comment: We don't know from where you are trying to "input" them, what format they are in (text or binary) or what hardware you even have.

Answer (score 1):

`in` is for loading a value from a port or some other I/O location. There are also several "load" instructions for putting values in registers. The one you choose depends on where the number is coming from. Basically, all the instructions that start with L, except for LSR and LSL are load instructions.

For example, `ldi r30, %22` puts hex 22 into register 30. (Here the number is in the program code.)